# Laravel Image Intervention avoid rotation

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm uploading an iPhone image - taken by iPhone camera in vertical - with the dimensions of `2448x3264` and because this dimensions are so high (?) when I create a thumb of `600x360` it automatically rotates to horizontal.

**What have I tried without any success**:

- Change the thumb dimensions
- Use the `fit` function
- Use the `resize` function
- Use the `crop` function
- Use the `upsize` and `aspectRatio` methods
- Set only the `height` and use null on `width`
- Set only the `width` and use null on `height`

The thumb must have a maximum of height of `360` and I'm ok if the width is not `600`.

```
$imageResize = Image::make($originalFile);
$imageResize->fit(600, 360, function ($constraint)
{
    $constraint->upsize();
});
$imageResize->save($thumbPath);
```

My goal is to have:

- Thumbnails in vertical if the original photo is vertical
- Thumbnails in horizontal if the original photo is horizontal

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Upon saving, is the original file in its original rotation? So if you manually went to the location, the file is in the correct rotation at it's default dimensions? [I found some information here that may suggest Laravel is rotating it upon uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277697/laravel-is-rotating-the-image-when-uploaded)

Comment: @swonder yes, the original image is saved with the default rotation/dimensions.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/461) as it seems to run inline with your question. It could be due to the `fit()` function.

Comment: @swonder the `orientate` method solved, would you like to set up as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As spoke before, the image is being saved in its correct orientation and at the point of resizing you are running the [`fit()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/fit) function on which I was able to find [some information on this issue](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/461) running along side that which suggests you need to use [`orientate()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/orientate) with fit.

An example here:

```
$imageResize = Image::make($originalFile);
$imageResize->orientate()
->fit(600, 360, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->upsize();
})
->save($thumbPath);
```

I'm glad this helped.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/461) you may need to run `orientate()` before `fit()`:

```
$imageResize = Image::make($originalFile)
    ->orientate()
    ->fit(600, 360, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->upsize();
    })
    ->save($thumbPath);
```

Answer (score 2):

```php
$img = Image::make($originalFile);

$img->orientate();
$img->resize(1024, null, function($constraint){
    $constraint->upsize();
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$img->save();
```

Comment: While your code snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how your code snippet works improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above will crop the image. To prevent that, you can slightly change code:

```
$imageResize = Image::make($originalFile);
$imageResize->orientate();
$imageResize->resize(600, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
    $constraint->upsize();
})->save($thumbPath);
```