# Laravel, rotating images expects parameter to be a valid path

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, file-read

When I upload images to the database Laravel rotates them, so I found
[Laravel is rotating the image when uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277697/laravel-is-rotating-the-image-when-uploaded), then after implementing it I get this error `exif_read_data() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given`. How can I fix this?

Controller

```
 if($request->hasFile('files')){

        $store_file = [];

        $exif = exif_read_data($request->file('files'));
        if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
            switch($exif['Orientation']) {
                case 8:
                    $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
                    break;
            }
        }


       // $files = $request->file('files');
        foreach ($exif as $file) {
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/photos');

            $store_file[] = [

                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'filename' =>  $path
            ];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ther error mentiened `exif_read_data() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given`.

You must provide image path from storage to `exif_read_data()` function which mean you need to loop through $request->file('files') and get the storage path via

```
$path = $file->store('public/photos');
```

Then

```
exif_read_data($path);
```

**Fix**

```
if($request->hasFile('files')){

    $store_file = [];

    foreach ($request->file('files') as $file) {

        $fileName = uniqid() . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $file->storeAs('public/photos', $fileName);

        $filePath = $file->getPathName();

        $exif = @exif_read_data($filePath);

        if(isset($exif['Orientation'])) {

            switch($exif['Orientation']) {
                case 8:
                    $deg = 90;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $deg = 180;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $deg = -90;
                    break;
            }

            if (isset($deg)) {

                $fullQualifiedFilePath = storage_path('app/public/photos/' . $fileName);

                if ($file->getClientOriginalExtension() == "png") {
                    $img_new = imagecreatefrompng($fullQualifiedFilePath);
                    $img_new = imagerotate($img_new, $deg, 0);

                    imagepng($img_new, $fullQualifiedFilePath);
                } else {
                    $img_new = imagecreatefromjpeg($fullQualifiedFilePath);
                    $img_new = imagerotate($img_new, $deg, 0);

                    imagejpeg($img_new, $fullQualifiedFilePath, 80);
                }
           }
       }

        $store_file[] = [

            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' =>  'public/photos/' . $fileName
        ];
    }

    ProductsPhoto::insert($store_file);
}
```

Reference [How to do a rotation of an image with PHP (Laravel)](https://guruquest.net/question/how-to-do-a-rotation-of-an-image-with-php-laravel/)

Comment: So where do I put this `exif_read_data()` code because I'm confused @Foued MOUSSI

Comment: I'm still getting `expects parameter to be a valid path` you may check the edited question @Foued MOUSSI

Comment: I'm getting `Undefined variable: exif"` @Foued MOUSSI

Comment: I'm getting another error `Call to a member function storeAs() on resource` @Foued MOUSSI

Comment: Try to comment this line `$image->storeAs('public/photos', $fileName);` and retry

Comment: It still rotating images but no errors @ Foued MOUSSI

Comment: Let me check  it

Comment: If you get an answer for that let me know(I'll appreciate it) @ Foued MOUSSI

Comment: Check it again plz

Comment: I get this error `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` `/storage/app/public/photos1581969650` @Foued MOUSSI

Comment: In which line ?

Comment: This line myproject/storage/app/public/photos1581969650 @Foued MOUSSI

Comment: Yes, sorry i'm black out just add '/' character after 'photos' like `$fullQualifiedFilePath = storage_path('app/public/photos/' . $fileName);`

Comment: And here also `$store_file[] = [

            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' =>  'public/photos/' . $fileName
        ];`

Comment: I'm still getting this `storage/app/public/photos/1581970076): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` @Foued MOUSSI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208007/discussion-between-foued-moussi-and-user11710915).

Comment: I have checked and now it uploads any image without errors but if I choose one image which doesn't need to be rotated and the one which needs to be rotated at the same time then uploads, the image which doesn't need to be rotated gets rotated and the one which needs to be rotated is fine . Another problem is if I choose 4 images or 2 then upload, it only uploads one images 4 times or 2 times(according to the chosen images(array)) @Foued MOUSSI